# Как скачать сайт сайт со всеми ресурсами?

Tags: linux, wget

Пытаюсь скачать сайт (страницу) которая находится по ссылке: [ссылка](http://web.olimpoks.com:9004/!/scorms.ecp/16/%D0%9E%D0%A2%201515.1_1/index.html)

Делаю это такой командой:

> wget -r -l10 -k -nd -e robots=off 'http://web.olimpoks.com:9004/!/scorms.ecp/16/%D0%9E%D0%A2%201515.1_1/index.html' -P /folder

В итоге скачивается, но не скачиваются ресурсы которые подгружаются динамически js скриптом.

Можно ли как-то скачать со всеми динамически подгружаемыми ресурсами?

Comment: wget так не умеет. Тут скорее всего нужно смотреть, что там хочется скачать и делать это все ручками или использовать какой-нибудь селениум.

Comment: А движок JS кто будет запускать?

Comment: @0andriy а это как?